# SSL: Error parsing the certificate: Ok

Tags: java, android, ssl

> **NOTE:** I ended up dropping support for Android 2.2 entirely, due to other problems... this issue remains a mistery though.

---

I have been experiencing a SSL exception in Android 2.2 on a Huawei U8150.

```
java.io.IOException: Error parsing the certificates: Ok
  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.nativeinit(Native Method)
  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.init(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:125)
  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:241)
  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper.java:35)
  at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:83)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPTCPConnection.java:739)
```

The code I'm using is fairly simple:
https://github.com/kontalk/androidclient/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/kontalk/client/KontalkConnection.java

The code above just sets a client certificate and a private key for authentication. The code works correctly on Android 2.3 and later.

I've inspected Apache Harmony code to understand what's hunder the hood, and it seems to fail when parsing the certificate chain: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/libcore/x-net/src/main/java/org/apache/harmony/xnet/provider/jsse/OpenSSLSocketImpl.java

In function `init()`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream certificateOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PEMWriter certificateWriter = new PEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(certificateOS));

for (int i = 0; i < certificates.length; i++) {
    certificateWriter.writeObject(certificates[i]);
}
certificateWriter.close();
```

It just uses a `PEMWriter` to create a concatenated chain in PEM format to pass it on to OpenSSL (via `nativeinit` function).

The certificate generated by my app is genuine, tested with `openssl x509`. I have to say it has a custom extension, but I repeat that any version newer than 2.2 just work.

I've uploaded the certificate here: http://paste.debian.net/209823/

---

**UPDATE**

I've been trying to reproduce on my desktop all the steps that Android does to reach the problematic point, that is (marked with **CHECK** the ones I've tried successfully):

1. store certificate into keystore
2. load certificate from keystore (in DER format) - **CHECK**
3. convert certificate to PEM format - **CHECK**
4. parse PEM certificate by OpenSSL - **CHECK**

For step 3 I'm using Bouncy Castle 1.49 with PEMWriter, just like Android does.
For step 4 I've created a small C utility linked against OpenSSL 0.9.8m (version installed in Android 2.2) that does the same function calls to initialize a SSL context and load a certificate from a file.

Now what I have left is:

- something wrong in keystore handling (I doubt that, although Android is known to have a crippled/modified version of Bouncy Castle)
- Android Java/Dalvik bug (unlikely, but still possible)
- exclude Android 2.2 completely (I'd rather not do it, especially because the issue could also be in other more recent versions that I haven't tried yet)

Code is posted here: https://gist.github.com/daniele-athome/47f458d64aefed6e6c11

Comment: Is the chain order correct?

Comment: No chain, the client certificate is self-signed. And the problem is on the client side: the client certificate isn't even provided to the server because it stops before that.